# PHP Photo incorrect format

Tags: php, http, http-post

I'm trying to upload a photo using a PHP HTTP Post but I'm getting the following error:

**Warning**:  imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error:  in **/home/randomma/public_html/RandomMash/Web Service/Main.php** on line **205**

**Warning**:  imagecreatefromstring(): Passed data is not in 'JPEG' format in **/home/randomma/public_html/RandomMash/Web Service/Main.php** on line **205**

**Warning**:  imagecreatefromstring(): Couldn't create GD Image Stream out of Data in **/home/randomma/public_html/RandomMash/Web Service/Main.php** on line **205**

**Warning**:  imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **/home/randomma/public_html/RandomMash/Web Service/Main.php** on line **205**

Here is the code I am using to try to save the file:

```
imagejpeg(imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($_POST["img"], TRUE)), "/Users/Images/20/".md5(uniqid()).".png");
```

Comment: what is in `$_POST["img"]`? is it really a valid image data?

Comment: It is, when I copy and paste the image data and manually type it in, it works fine.